# Using the OpenCV Phase Unwrapping Function in Python

Tags: python, opencv, unwrap

I would like to use the OpenCV phase unwrapping functions presented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3a/group__phase__unwrapping.html) in Python, but I've been unable to find the function inside the `cv2` namespace (this [module](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)). Has anyone else used this function outside of C++? I know there is an `unwrap` function in Numpy, but my goal is to use the OpenCV algorithm inside our production code in C# via the [OpenCVSharp Nuget package](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp), so it would be preferable to use the same OpenCV function in Python and C# than to use the Numpy unwrap function and rewrite it in C#. Has anyone been able to successfully use the OpenCV phase unwrapping functions outside of C++?

Comment: I ported the unwrapping code to C# and posted on Nuget for any interested parties - https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnwrapSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that if I `pip install opencv-contrib-python`, then I have the following functions available, which were not available before I installed opencv contrib

`cv2.phase_unwrapping_HistogramPhaseUnwrapping()`

and

`cv2.phase_unwrapping_PhaseUnwrapping()`

I believe these were the ones I was looking for, so the reason I couldn't find them before is that they were/are still contrib modules. Note that I'm using version 4.2.0 of OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

I have used phase unwrapping module in C++. For Python, I have seen that this module is available in cv2 namespace in Ubuntu 20.04 and Fedora 31.

Which distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.2.0 of OpenCV, installed via pip from the wheels [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/). I'm running on Windows 10 currently.

Comment: I have compiled my own OpenCV 4.3 with phase unwrapping support in Python at my home. However, due to corona virus related lockdown, I do not have appropriate data to test the code. Can you provide some matrices that you wish to unwrap? I can try with those else I will get back to you as soon as lockdown lifts here.

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, I don't need to unwrap matrices, I need to have that *capability* in my software. We were able to figure out an alternative though, using the [Scikit Image phase unwrapping](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_phase_unwrap.html). Thanks for the help though.